# AngularJS: 2 way binding in directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I have a directive as follows,

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.directive("checkTextCombo", [
      "$compile", function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          scope: {
            source: '@',
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.rows = eval('(' + scope.source + ')');
         },
          templateUrl: "../templates/check-text-combo/check-text-combo.html",
          controller: function($scope){
            $scope.$watch('$scope.rows', function() {
              console.log($scope.rows);
            });
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
```

And a template:

```
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.checked"/> <label value="{{row.label}}">{{row.label}}</label><input type="textbox" value="{{row.value}}" ng-disabled="!row.checked"/>
  </div>
```

`index.html` consists of

```
   <check-text-combo source="[{'value':'varsh','label':'name','checked': true}, {'value':'bij','label':'name','checked': false}]"></check-text-combo>
```

My problem is that, I can a create a template with `ng-repeat`, but after binding, when I change something in the template, it doesn't change elsewhere. How can I get the modified value?

Comment: may be $scope.$apply() can help!!

Comment: @Anita where will i add $scope.$apply()?

Comment: can u tell me what r u changing in template that is not being reflected?

Comment: i am checking or unchecking the checkbox or changing the text in textbox

Comment: I m not sure about the solution. But first you should add ng-model for each filed like checkbox ,input.. Also in input instead of using value property you should try ng-model=row.value.

Comment: And try adding $scope.$apply() at directive controller

Comment: u r correct.. adding ng-model did work

Comment: okay.. Then u shuld add vote up to my comment

Comment: I tried..but i cant.. since i don't have enough reputation :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working after adding ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.checked" ng-model="row.checked"/> <label value="{{row.label}}">{{row.label}}</label><input type="textbox" value="{{row.value}}" ng-model="row.value" ng-disabled="!row.checked"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to change your `$watch` definition:

```
$scope.$watch('rows', function() {
//              ^
//             Here
//    rows instead of $scope.rows
  console.log($scope.rows);
}, true);
//  ^
//and here
// third parameter to true - observed variable is an Object
```